# Raft: How to solve the performance bottleneck of leader node?

Tags: algorithm, distributed, consensus, raft

In raft, all operation requests will be forwarded to the leader node, and then the leader will send logs to all followers. So under a heavy loaded environment, the leader node will be a bottleneck. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved in different ways depending on your desires. Here are some example solutions.

**Partition the data.** Many large-scale systems partition the data to spread the load (as well as reduce hurt if a partition goes down). But transactions cannot cross partitions. That could be a bummer, depending on your application.

**Chain Consensus.** This protocol spreads the work of moving data to all the nodes in the cluster. There is still a leader that is a bottleneck for accepting data, but its burden is smaller. Chain consensus also leads to slightly higher latencies than a broadcast system.

Comment: What is chain consensus? Do you mean this http://dsrg.pdos.csail.mit.edu/2013/08/08/chain-replication/ ？

Comment: @huron That paper is where we started.